# Unnormalized data via resource in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, relational, ngresource

I am working on a WebApp using AngularJS. I have two main models, journeys and locations. Each journey has a start and an end destination.

On the server side I only handle normalized data, i.e., journeys and locations are stored in separate database tables, and each journey entry stores only the id numbers of its destinations.

On the client side (in AngularJS) I use two RESTful ngResources, one for journeys and one for locations. After loading both, I populate the journeys with the location data for display, such that journey contains not only startLocation (id) but also startLocationObject (location data) like this:

```
journey.startLocationObject = locations.byId(journey.startLocation);
```

ById is a simple lookup function that returns the location with the given id.

Now, every time I call $save on the journey, the location data is lost since the journey is overwritten with the server response. Thus, I have to repopulate the journey again with the location data.

Is there a nicer way to deal with this? For example, preventing ngResource from overwriting the journey object? Or am I missing something with regard to relational data in Angular?

Thanks for any help,
Best, Boris

Comment: There are many issues like that with this REST implementation. Perhaps you'll be fine with a custom implementation of your own. AFAIK you cannt overwrite that behavior.

Comment: You should implement a view on the server side that returns the journeys already associated with their locations. Be careful not to confuse your database tables with REST resources. The "R" in REST stands for "Representational." Create the representation on your server that best fits the needs of your client.

Comment: @Mike, I see, so that means populating the data on the server. I tried to avoid that in order to minimize network traffic, but maybe that's opening a can of worms. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

The way it must work is to get the data form the server and keep the client stateless.

For this reason, keeping the your "journey" data on the client is discouraged on REST applications.

The journey data would come from the server request or keep the journey data on another variable/collection before saving it.

Comment: Being stateless is a contradiction to caching and local storage for offline use, isn't it? I guess I might need to add that at some point, and then I have a local state anyway that needs to be synced with the server...

Comment: Yes, at some point, the client needs to keep data between requests.